# Webpack 2 - CSS links order

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am using `Webpack 2.6.1` with some loaders and plugins, including `ExtractTextPlugin`.

I have also included a `bootstrap-loader` to provide bootstrap for my HTML templates generated using `HtmlWebpackPlugin`.

Let's say I have this template configured:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  title: 'Index page',
  chunks: ['bootstrap', 'app'],
  filename: 'index.html', 
  template: './src/templates/index.ejs'
})
```

And in my **app.js** I require my styles like this:

```
require('../styles/app.scss');
```

The generated template in my `dist` folder includes both `bootstrap.css` and `app.css`, but in reverse order, so `app.css` is above the `bootstrap.css`.

How can I invert it, or control it?

Comment: Invert? What do you mean?

Comment: Check out `ExtractTextPlugin`

Comment: You could also do a no-op on your bootstrap styles and just have 2 style sheets.

Comment: @evolutionxbox So the `<link>` tag with `app.css` comes after that one with `bootstrap.css`
@mhatch I am using this plugin and I have this problem.

Comment: Um, have you tried to simply reverse the ordner of the `chunks` array?

Comment: @LarsBeck Yes, this was my first idea. Didn't work.

Comment: You should add a key to your HtmlWebpackPlugin parameter object: **chunksSortMode: 'none'**